# Category, list or venue group exclusive for my app

Tags: api, foursquare

I want to develop a web app and use in it the foursquare API, I need to add venues and filter them by location, likes, checkins, etc..
Would there be any way to create a category, list or venue group exclusive for the app, and do my inquiries directly to one of them.? I was thinking save the IDs Venues in my database, but as I want to filter by number of likes, checkins and others, that only will help me to bring data from a venue.

Answer (score 0):

The Foursquare venues database is for all to use, so when you make changes (adding venues, etc.) to it, they will be seen by the entire Foursquare community (app users, developers, etc.) Categories are curated by Foursquare itself, and there's no way to add them via the API.

There could be two approaches for you to take here, depending on your app's needs. You could simply retrieve venue data from Foursquare each time you need it, and then once you have these venues, perform the filtering you want. Since you also mentioned creating your own categories, you could also associate venue ID's with your custom categories locally.